# Servlets/JSP and multiple inserts to a database

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets

I have a page that takes student attendance. It prints out a student list with a checkbox next to each student. Then the person clicks submit and send the selected student's ids and the lab ids to the database.

The problem I'm having is its sending the last ticked box to the database and none of the rest. I'm assuming its overwriting the ones previous to it but I am unsure how I can fix this problem.

Here is my `doPost` method:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


            int user_id = Integer.parseInt((String)request.getParameter("user_id"));
            int lab_id =  Integer.parseInt((String)request.getParameter("lab_id"));


              System.out.println("I got a blow job");

              String message = null; 
              try {
                  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                  Connection con = 
                    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wae","root","");
                System.out.println("got connection"); 

                Statement s = con.createStatement(); 

                String sql = "INSERT INTO user_lab" + 
                          " (user_id, lab_id)" + 
                          " VALUES" + 
                          " ('" +  user_id + "'," + 
                             " '"  +  lab_id + "')"; 

                  System.out.println(sql);
                  int i = s.executeUpdate(sql); 
                  if (i==1) {
                    message = "Successful attendance."; 
                    response.sendRedirect("Tutor_labs");
                  } 

                  s.close(); 
                  con.close(); 
                } 
                catch (SQLException e) {
                  message = "Error." + e.toString(); 
                  boolean error = true; 
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                  message = "Error." + e.toString(); 
                  boolean error = true; 
                } 
                if (message!=null) {
                  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
                  out.println("<B>" + message + "</B><BR>"); 
                  out.println("<HR><BR>"); 
                } 

              } 

    }
```

and here is my JSP page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Mars University Lab System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>
<jsp:include page="headerTutor.jsp"/>

<div id = "centrecontent">
<h3>Students In Tutorial</h3>
<h2>Attendance List</h2>

<%
    String[] list1 = (String[])request.getAttribute("res1");
    String[] list2 = (String[])request.getAttribute("res2");
    String[] list3 = (String[])request.getAttribute("res3");
    String[] list4 = (String[])request.getAttribute("res4");

         if(null == list1){%>

<th>Uni Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Email</th>      
<% 
         }else{ %>

        <form name="ViewStudentsTutor" ACTION="http://www.crackman.net.au/ICE/test.php\"  method="post">
<%      for(int i=0; i<list1.length; i++)
        {   
            %>                  <input type="hidden" name="lab_id" value=<%=request.getParameter("labid")%>>
                                <%out.println(list2[i]);%>
                                <%out.println(list3[i]);%>
                                <%out.println(list4[i]); %>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="user_id" value=<%out.println(list1[i]);%>><br>


    <%  }}
    %>  
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"/>
        </form> 


</div>
<jsp:include page="footer.jsp"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking only one `user_id` using `request.getParameter("user_id")`
Instead you should use `request.getParameterValues("user_id")` that will return an array of `String` of all `user_id`s which you want and not a single `user_id` which currenlty you are getting

Similar is for `lab_id`

Comment: in the jsp or in the servlet should I be making these changes?

Comment: in the servlet because when you are making chekboxes using scriptlet then many checkboxes are created with the same name `user_id` so if you want all you need to change it in servlet with the above mentioned method.

Comment: when doing that I get the error Cannot cast from String[] to String

Comment: do like this `String user_id[] = request.getParameterValues("user_id");"` then you need to loop through the array, parse each `String` in `user_id` to int (as you are doing now) and then add that value in the database. This will add one entry for one iteration in the database. for subsequent iterations it will add all entries. Simlarly for `lab_id` if you need I can post code snippet for it

Comment: i am slightly confused as to how i would approach this, i assume i'd do a for loop where I'd write for(int i=0; i<user_id.length; i++){int user_id = Integer.parseInt((String)request.getParameter("user_id"));} but thats confusing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17666/discussion-between-user1393064-and-abu)