# How to insert Html table values into database using arrays in JSP

Tags: html, mysql, database, jsp

I want to insert the html table data rows into database using JSP.Please tell me how to do it using arrays or if any other methods please tell me.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Have you gone through basic tutorials for [tag:html-form] elements and other [html elements](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp), if yes than you would have already known that only through html form-elements like input, textarea, checkbox etc you can send data to server and not through `<table>`. Also it would be nice to know if you have also gone through basic tutorials for [tag:jsp] & [tag:servlets] and how they interact with [tag:database]. Now lastly please tell us what you have actually tried and where you are stuck, so that we can help you move forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the array values from the jsp , and in servlet you can get them through ,

```
String[] arrayVar= request.getParameterValues("YourJspArrayAttribute");
```

you can find some examples in so ,

1. [inserting java array values into mysql by using prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629665/inserting-java-array-values-into-mysql-by-using-prepared-statement)
2. [Servlets/JSP and multiple inserts to a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766624/servlets-jsp-and-multiple-inserts-to-a-database)